# On boiling, does 1 kg of water give rise to 1 kg of steam?

Tags: evaporation, thought-experiment

I understand that by conservation of mass, it implies that 1 kg of water will give rise to 1 kg of steam.

But when I consider the fact that there is phase change which is an abrupt and discontinuous change in the density of the fluid and it seems to me somewhat plausible to even consider this question.

Comment: Why do you think mass would not be conserved? If there is no mass entering or leaving your system then how can the total amount of matter change?

Comment: @JohnRennie: $E=mc^2$, so some mass might be sneakiing in.

Answer (score 6):

A water molecule is a water molecule, irrespective if it is densly packed with other water molecules (forming a liquid phase) or if it is widely separated from other water molecules (forming a vapor phase). So it seems obvious that boiling one kilogram of water gives you exactly one kilogram of steam.

But boiling off water requires energy...

... and didn't Einstein tell us that energy and mass are equivalent?

Indeed, if you look at the physics more closely, you discover that boiling a kilogram of water gives you a tiny bit more than a kilogram of steam.

The mass of a number of water molecules density packed together (in the liquid phase) is a little less than the mass of the same number of water molecules separated from each other. This missing mass (or mass defect) represents the intermolecular binding energy of the water molecules in the liquid phase.

This binding energy is the energy you need to put in to split liquid water into individual molecules. This binding energy is tiny. Two water molecules are bound together into a [water dimer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_dimer) (a 'liquid drop' consisting of only two molecules) with a binding energy E of about $2 \times 10^{-20}$ J. Splitting them apart results into a mass increase of $m = E/c^2 = 2 \times 10^{-37}$ kg. This mass increase is small compared to the mass of the water dimer ($6 \times 10^{-26}$ kg). It follows that the relative mass increase is as small as $3$ parts in $10^{12}$.

As a water molecule in the liquid phase is surrounded by several other molecules, it is more strongly bonded than a water molecule in a dimer. I estimate that the mass defect for water molecules bound in the liquid phase is probably as large as $10$ parts in $10^{12}$.

So, boiling a kilogram of water generates a kilogram *plus about ten nanogram* of steam.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no mass leaving or coming into the system, notwithstanding the seeming complexity of phase change, and indeed one kilogram of water must evaporate to 1 kg of steam: there is no "trick" here.

There is a tiny correction to this statement if you want to look at really fine details. Quite a deal of energy goes into the water to boil it. You're giving each molecule enough energy to overcome the mutual attraction between it and its neighbours: in most liquids this quite significant. For water, the so-called latent heat of vaporisation is 2260 kilojoules per kilogram. Relativisically speaking, because the water's internal energy has risen, both its inertial and gravitational mass - the same thing from the point of view of special relativity (and approximately in general relativity - see footnote) - rises by $\Delta E/c^2$, which amounts to $2.5\times 10^{-13}{\rm kg}$ or about a quarter of a billionth of a gram for each kilogram of water you have before evapouration. There is further energy in the amount 4.2kJ per kilogram per kelvin of temperature rise before boiling, but this tends to be small compared with the latent heat of vapourisation.

Footnote: In general relativity, the "source" terms for Einstein's field equations are the stress energy tensor, not a simple scalar like a mass. However, to say that mass has risen by a quantity $E/c^2$ is an excellent approximation (*i.e.* the $0\,0$ component of the stress energy tensor has risen by  $E/c^2$)

Answer (score 3):

From a molecular perspective there is nothing discontinuous about a phase change. It is just molecules provided with enough energy to escape from the bulk fluid and fly into the gas phase*.

From that same perspective you also know that each molecule has a certain mass, so upon moving from the bulk fluid to the steam, the steam becomes slightly heavier (more molecules) and the bulk fluid slightly lighter (less molecules), by the amount of the mass of 1 molecule of water. Considering this process I think it is clear that 1 kg of liquid water will indeed give rise to 1 kg of steam, because there are no molecules lost.

*Actually, on a molecular scale it is not that straightforward to identify the phase boundary between liquid and gas, because the interface is a transition region of several molecular diameters